# ORACLE - Setting RANK of duplicated on a big table, optimization needed

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery, query-optimization

This is a simplified extract for a more complex algorithm.
The problem is I have a simple table C_HASH like this:

```
CREATE TABLE C_HASH
    (   
    HASH CHAR (48),
    RANK INTEGER
    );
```

First I fill the table with all the hash values. But because I can have duplicates in HASH, to identify the duplicates one by one I need to set the RANK by HASH.

I do this SQL statement but it is way to long, I have indexed the HASH column, with no effect:

```
UPDATE C_HASH a set RANK = ( select temp.rank from ( select rowid, rank() over ( PARTITION BY HASH ORDER BY ROWID ) rank from C_HASH ) temp where temp.rowid = a.rowid);
```

I need to optimize this! A clue?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `merge` syntax:

```
merge into c_hash c
using (
    select rowid, row_number() over(partition by hash order by rowid) rank
    from c_hash
) c1
on (c1.rowid = c.rowid)
when matched then update set c.rank = c1.rank
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3b5d962cc4b4ac13a9e2d2a22e2614e7)**

Sample data:

```
HASH                                             | RANK
:----------------------------------------------- | ---:
foo                                              | null
foo                                              | null
foo                                              | null
bar                                              | null
```

Results:

```
HASH                                             | RANK
:----------------------------------------------- | ---:
foo                                              |    1
foo                                              |    2
foo                                              |    3
bar                                              |    1
```

---

If you are going to update a lot of rows, it might be more efficient to create a new table, using the `insert ... select` syntax:

```
create table c_hash2 as
select hash, row_number() over(partition by hash order by rowid) as rank
from c_hash
```

Answer (score 1):

This is going to take a long time, because you are updating all rows.  But you can simplify the logic to:

```
update c_hash h
    set rank = (select count(*)
                from c_hash h2
                where h2.hash = h.hash and h2.rowid <= h.rowid
               );
```

This should be table to take advantage of your existing index.